# Jenkins won't trigger build after merging a pull request in GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins

So far triggering a build in Jenkins work's fine for creating a new pull request, pushing changes and leaving a comment like `test this please` however, when I hit green "Merge pull request" button in GitHub, I don't see any jobs running in Jenkins.

**MY JOB SETTINGS**

Refspec: `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`

Branch Specifier: `origin/master` or `${sha1}`

Took [GitHub pull request builder plugin documentation][1] as reference.

**JENKINS LOGS**

```
Jan 14, 2017 10:50:17 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRootAction handleAction
INFO: Checking PR #3 for Username/project
Jan 14, 2017 10:50:17 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger handlePR
INFO: Checking PR #3 for job Nation
Jan 14, 2017 10:50:17 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
INFO: Received PushEvent for https://github.com/Username/project
Jan 14, 2017 10:50:17 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRootAction handleAction
WARNING: Request not known for event: push

Jan 14, 2017 10:50:28 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRootAction handleAction
WARNING: Request not known for event: push
Jan 14, 2017 10:50:28 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
INFO: Received PushEvent for https://github.com/Username/project
```

**GITHUB WEBHOOK LOGS**

**Log 1)**
Request
`X-GitHub-Event: pull_request`
Payload
`.... "action": "closed" ...`

**Log 2)**
Request
`X-GitHub-Event: push`
Payload
`.... "ref": "refs/heads/develop" ...`

**Log 3)**
Request
`X-GitHub-Event: push`
Payload
`.... "ref": "refs/heads/feature/update-gitignore" ...`

---

**UPDATE**

I have `Pull request`, `Issue comment` and `Push` events are enabled in GitHub Webhook Setting page.

Comment: Did you install Github plugin in Jenkins and Jenkins plugin on Github? They work together

Comment: I have "Git plugin", "GitHub plugin" and "GitHub Pull Request Builder" plugins are installed. The webhook and the service in GitHub are set as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to create two different items. One for pull request builder and another for pull request merger.

Whole example/answer is here: [Setup GitHub and Jenkins integration for pull request builder and merger](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ljgv/setup-github-and-jenkins-integration-for-pull-request-builder-and-merger)

The difference is explained under bullet point 13 and 14. `14. Configure Jenkins project - Nation-Merge` is the one solved my problem.

- `Refspec` is blank.
- Type `origin/develop` in "Branch Specifier" field.
- Tick "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" option.

Answer (score 2):

Merge should be part of a regular push changed request and might not be handled by Pull Request Builder plugin but rather standard github plugin (as it is not a pull request anymore).

I don't know what type of job you are using (pipeline, DSL, ...), but ...

From your logs, I can tell that you have different branches where you push changes on merge, they are "develop" and "feature" while in branch specifier you have origin/master, so it will ignore changes to any of the other branches.

Comment: I have "GitHub plugin" installed and used `${sha1}` for Branch Specifier but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your refspec focused on pullrequest. Try to leave refspec blank

Comment: Hmm that`s strange. Pull builds should disabled and branch build should start. Could your show settings screen?

Comment: Please see images above.

Comment: Fine!
This is two different process build on pull request and build in branch change.
We create two different builds and check "request scm on changes" or something like this