# pull request hotfix to prod and dev

Tags: git, devops, git-flow

Working with github and pull requests flow.
In case of a bug in production, i open a hotfix/branch in order to resolve the issue, compile, test, and opening a pull request back to master branch (the production branch in our case).
Is there an option to let this pull request to automatically merged as well to dev branch?
I'm looking for an easy way to handle these cases, and to avoid as much as possible additional human evolvement and mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

As [described in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41704173/6309), you can setup a [Jenkins job](https://jenkins.io/) that will:

- monitor any new GitHub pr branch
- fetch and try to merge them.

If the merge has any conflict, the second job will fail (and can send an email to the team)

Comment: Basically we have set kind of pipeline with teamcity. The issue i'm tryong to understand is if there is any convinient way to do it , regardless the job, or i should merge the hotfix/feature to each of the branches manually. and for that it will require 2 differemt PR?

Comment: @user4860092 OK. Same idea. But with TeamCity.

Comment: what is the suggested way to make this hotfix from master branch and then to make sure it's also in dev branch. considering dev branch is saved by pushing without PR

Comment: @user4860092 simply make two merges: one from pr t master, one from pr to dev.

Comment: open 2 differnt PR or can i use the same PR to make merge to both of them.
i'm using github..

Comment: @user4860092 same PR: once the branch has been fetch by the CI tool, that same job can make two merges, from the same PR branch to two destination branches.

Comment: @VonX i couldn't find a way to push to dev branch and to master with 1 PR.
i'd love to hear how it can be done, or if you have any good reference i can learn from. both dev and master are protected from being push new commits with no pr.
so using 1 pr to both branches with fetch isn't helping here.... am i missing something ?

Comment: @user4860092 You generally don't push a branch which is common with the original repo. If 'dev' or 'master' exist in the original repo, don't use them in your own fork. Always push a new fix branch (`my_fix_branch` or something). Then make a PR from that new pushed branch to uptream dev or master.

Comment: let me try to refrase what i have tried to understand. i'm working in the following order. bug found on master -> branch from master to hotfix/bug-fix -> PR hotfix/bug-fix to master -> merge to master. now i'm looking to find what is the preferable way to make sure this is also merged back to dev. the fastest solution i have came to my mind, is to create a new PR from the hotfix/bug-fix branch to dev and merge. just wondered if there is something easier or better approach

Comment: @user4860092 not that I know of, especially with dev and master protected.

Comment: and from your expirience what that i have suggested is it sounds to you, open 2 pull request from the specific branch ?

Comment: @user4860092 Yes. A single PR would not be enough. You can change the target branch of a PR (https://blog.github.com/2016-08-15-change-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request/), but represents only one PR at a time, not two concurrent PRs.

Comment: after i am merging a PR to master it cannot be eddited any more as the base branch

Comment: @user4860092 Yes, that is what I meant by "A single PR would *not* be enough"